# SerialPort1 Receiving Data

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I'm trying to make a small program that pulls in RS232 serial data and I'm not handling it too well.  Likely because I'm a little lost.  I open the serial port at form load event.  I have a GPS device which could use any baudrate so what I want to do is iterate through all the baudrates on my PC (all of this nonchalantly) so that the PC automatically finds the baudrate.  I'm looking for the GGA characters, which is a standard NMEA output.  My program works to some extent, but sometimes I get cross threading issues.  And on one PC my program just disappears (sometimes). If I put the thread to sleep for a couple of seconds it seems a little more stable, but not always.   I'm liking the idea of background worker with the whole percentage thing too, which may help getting rid of bugs, but I'm not entirely sure how to impliment that or why it's cross threading in the first place.  Here is my code so far.  Can someone explain why this cross threading exists?

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        //backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }


    }
    
    
   
    private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)

    {
        try
        {
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                label1.Text = "stringfound calculating";
            }));
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            FindTheSerialStringBaudAndType();
        }

        catch (Exception Ex) 
        { MessageBox.Show(Ex.ToString()); }
    }
    private void FindTheSerialStringBaudAndType()
    {
        try
        {
            string TryReadingData;
            TryReadingData = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            serialPort1.Close();

            if (TryReadingData.Contains("$GPGGA") == true)
            {

                textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    textBox1.Text = TryReadingData.ToString();
                }));

                label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    label1.Text = "Found GGA string on port 1 @ " + serialPort1.BaudRate.ToString() + " baudrate";
                }));
            }



            else
            {

                ChangeBaudrate();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        { MessageBox.Show(EX.ToString()); }
    }
   

    private void ChangeBaudrate()
    {
        try
        {
            switch (serialPort1.BaudRate)
            {
                case 115200:
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = 57800;
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    break;
                case 57800:
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = 38400;
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    break;
                case 38400:
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = 19200;
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    break;
                case 19200:
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    break;
                case 9600:
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = 4800;
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    break;
                case 4800:
                    serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    break;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EX.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: It'll save you a lot of coding errors if you avoid writing `catch (Exception EX) { MessageBox.Show(EX.ToString()); }`. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle.

Comment: You're making life hard for yourself. `TryReadingData` is a `string` so there is no need to do `.ToString()` on it.

Comment: It seems wrong that you're handling the `DataReceived` event and then trying to set the baud. Perhaps look at this app and see if it helps? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75770/Basic-serial-port-listening-application

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what you're trying to say about my catch handler?  I have a message box showing me the error.  If it's not there the minute I go to a PC with no debugging then Microsoft windows usually hangs up and doesn't handle it very well.  On the Tostring subject.  Microsoft Windows has not been very friendly in the past converting strings automatically.

Comment: Yes I am trying to set the baudrate automatically when the serial cable is plugged in.  Much like when a USB cable is plugged in.  I don't want the user to have much interaction with this.  If the baudrate is wrong all that happens is wrong characters that show up.  So if there's no correct characters then the baudrate is wrong then that will change in my program.   The program you sent me maybe helpful though.  Thanks